# Redirect set of included URL patterns in django

Tags: django

For my Django app, I've always had my Dashboard pages prefixed with `/site/dashboard/`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('site/dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
]
```

I'd like to simplify the URLs and change it so the pages are just `/dashboard/`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
]
```

I'm familiar with doing a [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) in URLs to redirect to a different single url/view. How would I do this with an entire set of views, so all the old `/site/dashboard/` URLs in `dashboard.urls` were marked with a 301 redirect to the new URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but judging by the description, [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/redirects/#module-django.contrib.redirects) is what you need.

To install,

1. add it to your settings.py:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware
]

SITE_ID=1
```

2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. [Add redirect in the admin interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/redirects/#via-the-admin-interface)